# find in MongoCollection<Document>

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a `MongoCollection<Document>` in which I assign a collection.
I'm trying to find a user by his id.

```
user = (Document) usersCollection.find(new Document("_id", username));
```

with that I'm getting an error

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mongodb.FindIterableImpl cannot be
>   cast to org.bson.Document

When I try

```
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject(); 
    BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("_id", username);
    usersCollection.find(query, fields);
```

I'm getting an error

> The method find(Bson, Class) in the type MongoCollection is not applicable for the arguments (BasicDBObject, BasicDBObject)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try to create a filter to pass to the [**`find()`**](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/getting-started/quick-tour/) method to get a subset of the documents in your collection. For example, to find the document for which the value of the `_id` field is `test`, you would do the following:

```
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*;

MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("mydb");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("mycoll");
Document myDoc = collection.find(eq("_id", "test")).first();
System.out.println(myDoc.toJson());
```

Comment: Where can I find eq() operator?

Comment: @DarshanPuranik `import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.eq;`

Comment: @DarshanPuranik `eq()` is a static method and on hover of static methods, Eclipse does not give an import suggestion. In this case you need to explicitly add the import statement and also for all the other similar methods.

Comment: here what is the type of myDoc?

Comment: @Srikanth `Document`

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you assume that the `find()` method returns a single `Document`. It doesn't. It returns a list of them.

In MongoDB 2 Java driver there was a method on the `DBCollection` class named `findOne()`. In the MongoDB 3 Java driver API, the `findOne()` method isn't there. So your new code for finding exactly one document becomes similar too this one:

```
collection.find(eq("_id", 3)).first()
```

where `eq("_id", 3)` is called a filter on your collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
MongoCollection<Document> filterCriteriaDoc = mongoDatabase.getCollection("documentName");

Document filterDoc = new Document();

filterDoc.put("col1", "value");

filterDoc.append("col2", "value");

filterDoc.append("col2", "value");

Iterator<Document> iter = filterCriteriaDoc.find(filterDoc).iterator();
```

`iter.next()` can give you document .

Comment: Please put code blocks between fences to make it more readable and enable syntax highlighting.

Comment: yeah sure will do that

Answer (score -1):

If you using IP to connect to MongoDb here how you do it change **HEREYOURIP**

**import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.eq;**

```
public static Document GetDocumentFromDataBase(String dataBase,String DBcollection,String field, String value) {
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(  " HEREYOURIP ",27017 );
MongoDatabase database =  mongoClient.getDatabase(dataBase);
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(DBcollection);
Document myDoc = collection.find(eq(field, value)).first();
    mongoClient.close();
    return myDoc;}
```

**edited** found other way do it

```
public static String GetFromDB(String DATABASE_NAME,String collectionName, String field, String value) {
        String valueBack;
        BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
        whereQuery.put("_id", new ObjectId(value));
        
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(System.getenv("HERE_YOUR_DB_IP"), 27017);
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(collectionName);
        Document myDoc = collection.find(whereQuery).first();
        if (myDoc != null) {

            valueBack = myDoc.toString();
            mongoClient.close();
            return valueBack;
        }
        mongoClient.close();
        return null;

    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Do this -

```
 MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
    DBObject resultObject  = new BasicDBObject("_id", username);
    MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("DBNAME");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection =  database.getCollection("COLLECTION_NAME");
    DBObject dbObject  = new BasicDBObject("_id", username);
    resultObject   = collection.find(dbObject).next();
    String result =  resultObject.get(YOUR_COLOUM_NAME);
```