# Java MongoClient - How to find document and return specific objects

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

Using the java `MongoClient` library, how can I find a document in a collection and only return specific `Objects`? I know this is possible for 1 `Object` but not sure about multiple.

**For 1 `Object`:**

```
DBCursor cursor = db.getCollection(collectionName).find(dbObject)
```

**Possibly for 2 `Objects`??:**

```
DBCursor cursor = db.getCollection(collectionName).find(dbObject1, dbObject2, dbObject3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your question finds an answer in this poll: [find in MongoCollection<Document>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30625380/find-in-mongocollectiondocument)

Anyway, for one object:

```
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*;
 MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
 MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("mydb");
 MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("mycoll");
 myDoc = collection.find(eq("_id", "42")).first(); //finds object with _id equals to 42
```

For finding many objects there can be many solutions, it is hard to reply without knowing better your data. I would check this out: http://www.thejavageek.com/2015/08/24/retrieve-documents-from-mongodb-using-java/ or the official documentation as well 
https://resources.mongodb.com/getting-started-with-mongodb?_ga=2.26976315.702528013.1555420535-809832624.1541599802

Good luck!