# Jmeter - How to get the last Username from the mongoDB from dynamic JSON

Tags: mongodb, jmeter

I am very new at mongoDB, and I am trying to get the last Username(int) from dynamic json.
The value of the username is always dynamic

Having mongoDB json as:

```
{
    "_id": "39ecb71e-9641-4c7a-9f97-ebe33458e125",
    "Username": "043020229",
    "Name": "test1",
    "Surname": "Tesfye",
    "Email": "ab@gmail.com",
    "Status": "UNCONF",
    "DateOfBirth": {
        "$date": "1982-02-25T15:24:17.923Z"
    },
    "RegistrationDate": {
        "$date": "2021-07-13T14:24:25.991Z"
    },
    "ActivitySouce": "test",
    "Password": "test"  
}

{
    "_id": "b6acb1ea-9629-42ea-94ce-71fc6812301d",
    "Username": "095262760",
    "Name": "test2",
    "Surname": "test",
    "Email": "ad@gmail.com",
    "Status": "ACT",
    "DateOfBirth": {
        "$date": "1981-08-31T14:24:54.166Z"
    },
    "RegistrationDate": {
        "$date": "2021-07-110T14:24:53.212Z"
    },
    "ActivitySouce": "test",
    "Password": "test"
}
```

What I tried using Jmeter JRS223 sampler is:

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates;
import com.mongodb.client.model.Accumulators;
import com.mongodb.client.model.Projections;
import com.mongodb.client.model.Filters;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.eq;
import com.gmongo.*;
import com.mongodb.*;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;                    // import DBCollection class
import org.bson.types.ObjectId
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject
import com.mongodb.*


try {

    MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://localhost:27017/?readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&ssl=false");
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("FFF");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("Users");

    
    
    Document result = collection.find().sort(new Document("Username", -1)).limit(1);

    
    vars.put("Username", result.get("Username").toString());




    mongoClient.close()
}
catch (Exception e) {
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
    SampleResult.setResponseCode("500");
    SampleResult.setResponseMessage("Exception: " + e);
}
```

the error that i am seeing is:

```
Response code:500
Response message:Exception: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'com.mongodb.client.internal.Java8FindIterableImpl@43dd792c' with class 'com.mongodb.client.internal.Java8FindIterableImpl' to class 'org.bson.Document'
```

How can I get the latest Username, having this set-up?

Every help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code:

```
Document result = collection.find().sort(new Document("Username", -1)).limit(1);
```

gives you a [FindIterable](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/latest/com/mongodb/client/FindIterable.html) instance, you need to invoke the relevant function in order to get the [Document](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.9/javadoc/org/bson/Document.html)

So you can quickly fix your script by adding `.take(1)` to the end of your line:

```
Document result = collection.find().sort(new Document("Username", -1)).limit(1).take(1);
```

More information:

- [find in MongoCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30625380/find-in-mongocollectiondocument)
- [MongoDB Performance Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mongodb-performance-testing-with-jmeter)